# Is it considered cheating to use multiple devices?

Tags: ingress

Until such time that I have a power pack I'm considering installing ingress on an old phone so I can keep playing longer. 
Assuming I can get it running would this constitute cheating? 
I can't find anything in the terms of service,  surprisingly even about using 2 devices at the same  time (though I'm not sure what you would gain by doing  so)

Since  my intention is to increase playing time obviously I intend to use only one device at a time

Comment: If you want to downvote please say why,  otherwise I can't learn from my mistake

Comment: Not a downvoter, but: your question is asking if something is against the ToS. This would typically invite a downvote from me for not doing the research. **However**, you claim to have already looked through the ToS. Thus, you aren't asking if it's against the ToS as much as you're asking whether it's cheating or not. I suggest that you reword your question.

Comment: Thanks @Schism that kind of makes sense. I only hope my rewording doesn't mean the answer is an opinion rather than fact

Comment: The only one who can say if it's against the TOS or cheating are the developers themselves.  Everything else is conjecture.

Comment: @Frank Couldn't someone read the TOS to find out if it's against the TOS?

Comment: @Unionhawk If the Terms of Service weren't loaded with lawyer speak and actually were as clear as you'd hope, sure!  Sadly, it's got lots of interpretation, and very unclear in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 6):

It's not very clear but using two different devices would/could be considered cheating.

Read the "Cheating" clause on this page where it says:

> Remember Ingress is meant to be played **on a mobile device**

https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808360?hl=en

Again one of this post's answers mentions a Niantic founder's (John Hanke) explanation on the matter but it's completely hearsay:

> This matches up with what John Hanke described to some players at the recent Amsterdam anomaly (cut 'n pasted from one of those players)
>   iitc = no ban, no problem
>   mirror download = no
>   Google Play Store signature = ban
>   modded apk = ban
>   multi device = ok
>   multi account (via same Play Store signature) = ban
>   if you use another email on ingress, than you used on Playstore = ok
>   merchandising = OK as long as its reasonable.
>   if not reasonable, they ask politely to stop. and there could be an opening for licence

http://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/23y48m/bans_bans_b

And this old post from Niantic's Google Groups era (even if it's not what you mean) warns about account ban.

> Question: Has anyone tried log on one account on two phones at two different places?
>   What will happen now?
>   What should happen(official)?
>
> Answer: Players have been reported/banned for this

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ingress-discuss/2lTvWEUP8wQ

I would suggest you not to use a second device and to buy a battery pack. It should be much easier to carry a battery pack than using a second phone.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find anything in any of those posts that states multiple devices is a problem (one of them actively says it's ok) but for now I think I'll wait for a more definite answer, or until I have a power pack

Comment: Please summarize the information contained at the links.  Without that, if those pages go down, your answer loses value.  It also saves people a click.