# Is there a legitimate way to play Pokemon Go on multiple phones?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have two phones that I normally carry with me, one iPhone and one Android. They are on different networks, so I would like to be able to play Pokemon Go on one or the other depending on which has superior signal where I am. However, I don't want to get banned for cheating.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possibly Related: [Is it considered cheating to use multiple devices?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183433/is-it-considered-cheating-to-use-multiple-devices) While Ingress is different it is ran by the same company, and Pokemon Go uses very similar mechanics

Answer (score 1):

When you download and start up Pokemon Go on the second phone for the first time, choose to log in with the same network (Google or Trainer) and enter the same information. That will log you into the same account as the other phone. This is not considered cheating, as it's still just one account.

Comment: Any reference for this? Wondercricket's comment implies that Niantic bans people for this kind of behavior, so an official declaration would be the best.